# remove the Video view's Seekbar in android

Tags: android

I have one VideoView in my Android application.I want to remove the  Video view's Seekbar or Progressbar in android.How to do it?
Thanks for any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`VideoView` does not have a "Seekbar or Progressbar".

If you attached a `MediaController` to the `VideoView`, *that* is what has a "Seekbar or Progressbar". If you do not want a `MediaController`, remove your code that added one to the `VideoView`.